# setLookAtM not working or missing

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

I am following a simple tutorial to draw using OpenGL ES2.0 and I am setting up my own transformation matrix. However, the function Matrix.setLookAtM() does not work. Eclipse gives me

**The method setLookAtM(float[], float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float) is undefined for the type Matrix.**

But it's correct as I even copy pasted it from
[Android Matrix docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html) Did it import the wrong Matrix class? Google isn't turning up results. Where or how can I fix it? My code is:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

    private float[] modelViewMatrix = new float[16];

    GLRenderer(){
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated( GL10 gl, EGLConfig config ) {
        GLES20.glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

        Matrix.setLookAtM( modelViewMatrix, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged( GL10 gl, int width, int height ) {
        //...
    }

    public void onDrawFrame( GL10 gl ) {
            //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It imported the wrong class. **BEWARE** Eclipse auto import!

Wrong auto imported class:

```
import android.graphics.Matrix;
```

Correct class:

```
import android.opengl.Matrix;
```